# HttpRequestHandler in ArcGIS SDK Android 100.X?

Tags: url, http, arcgis-runtime-sdk-android

Il have a service that is exposed to external requests with the adress `https://proxyUlrPrefix/arcgis/rest/...` It works well to access it and I can display my maps on my mobile app.

When I try to generate a geodatabase to get for offline use though, my server sends the official URL for him on where to get the geodatabase. He gives me an URL like `http://myServerName:6080/arcgis/rest/...` . Because this URL is not accessible, I cannot get my offline map. So when the request is sent from my mobile to the server, I would like to replace the url `myServerName` with `proxyUrlPrefix` so the access is granted.

I saw on the .net SDK that the event [ArcGISHttpClientHandler.HttpRequestBegin Event](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/android/api-reference/html/E_Esri_ArcGISRuntime_Http_ArcGISHttpClientHandler_HttpRequestBegin.htm) can be used. In the Android SDK v.10.2.7, it's also available as mentioned in [Setting up HttpRequestConfiguration to ArcGIS Android SDK for security](https://community.esri.com/thread/170497) . In the Android SDK 100.7, I only found [RequestConfiguration (ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android 100.7.0)](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/io/RequestConfiguration.html)  that I can use to set headers, but not in order to manipulate the request URL.

Has anyone an idea on why this class is not implemented in the Android SDK and how I can modify my URL?

This question is also posted on [GeoNet](https://community.esri.com/thread/247172-httprequesthandler-in-arcgis-sdk-android-100x)

Comment: Slashes are not permitted in a server hostname, which degrades the quality of this question.